# ListView with images and datatriggers don't displayed

Tags: c#, wpf

I wan't to make something like this in wpf [image]

So i try this xaml:

```
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StateItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="vm:StateItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{StaticResource Ellipse}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{StaticResource EllipseEmpty}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

And this in viewModel:

```
  public List<StateItem> StateItems
    {
        get
        {
            var items = new StateItem[m_InstallationSteps.Steps.Count];
            items[m_InstallationSteps.ActiveStepIndex].Active = true;
            return items.ToList();
        }
    } 
public class StateItem
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

But it does not appear. How to make it appear?

EDIT:
It seems to me that binding don't work

EDIT2: try to change with notify but it didn't help

```
  public class StateItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool m_Active;

    public bool Active
    {
        get { return m_Active; }
        set
        {
            m_Active = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Active");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the DataContext with ViewModel? And does StateItems has already items when UI is loaded? Otherwise you have to notify the UI about changes.

Comment: not sure, how to set it?

Comment: Did you try adding something like <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource EllipseEmpty}" /> just before the triggers to put a default value ? Also, maybe you should try putting a NotifyPropertyChanged-like call in Active property's setter.

Comment: I try to add   <ListView.Items>
                    <vm:StateItem Active="True" />
                </ListView.Items> and it's work

Comment: Yes, I think it's because of a NotifyPropertyChanged missing in the Active property setter. Or making it a Dependency Property if you ViewModel is a DependencyObject.

Comment: DataContext you can set e.g. in Window constructor with `this.DataContext = new YourViewModel();`.

Comment: Edit in post with NotifyPropertyChanged but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fool)) problem is   `items[m_InstallationSteps.ActiveStepIndex].Active = true;`.

It was null but wpf did not  throw exception.